# Calling other plugins within a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

In order to clean up my code i want to use sub-plugins within my actual jQuery plugin, but actually there is nothing happening. thx in advance

As an easy example, please take a look at the following code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.funct = function() {
        // so far it seems to run the code...
        console.log('funct is running...');

        return this.each(function(){
            // ...but nothing is happening here
            console.log('this.each is running...');
            $(this).css('background', 'blue');
        }
    } 
    $.fn.foo = function() { 
        return this.each(function(){
            console.log('plugin is running...');
            $(this).funct();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At initial glance, it looks like you're not closing the first return properly.

```
$(this).css('background', 'blue');
        }
```

should be:

```
$(this).css('background', 'blue');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to fire a custom event in one plugin and let the other plugin subscribe to that event. The you do not have the dependency.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238293/global-event-registry-with-jquery) for more info regarding custom events and binding/triggering