# How to use one jQuery plugin from within another?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a jQuery plugin which needs to rely on jQuery++, but I am unsure how to reference it from my plugin. How do I do so?

Comment: As long as the other plugin is loaded before this one, it should work normally. Perhaps if you gave an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Juhana I was about to write that ;)

Comment: Agh, turns out I was just using the plugin wrong and now feel like an idiot. Sorry guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
$.getScript("other_scripts.js", function(){

   // You can use anything you defined in other_scripts.js here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.funct = function() {
        console.log('funct is running...');
    } 
    $.fn.foo = function() { 
        return this.each(function(){
            console.log('plugin is running...');
            $(this).funct();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Code copied and modified from [Calling other plugins within a jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238841/calling-other-plugins-within-a-jquery-plugin)